# How do low frequency radio waves bend due to diffraction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, radio

I did not understand how do surface waves follow the curvature of the earth by diffraction. Here is an excerpt from the book that I was reading from.
[image]

```
This is from "Radio Navigation" - JAA ATPL Training by Jeppesen
```

Comment: There is some [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_wave#Electromagnetic_waves).